# Weird popup when I try to copy a file

Tags: windows-8, laptop, desktop, file-transfer

Here is the popup I get: [image]

Now before I get this popup, It says something like:"Copying 39.785 files" and then immediatly shows me this. How come I get this and how can I make it stop?

Comment: Please elaborate a bit - so what is the source folder? and how big are these files, type if possible might also help a bit

Comment: @Rudolph I am getting the file from a zip from the desktop

Comment: Okay so the zip file is currently on the desktop, and you are extracting the compressed files to the desktop. Have you tried creating a new folder on the desktop and extracting the zip files to that folder?

Comment: @Rudolph yeah I did but I want to know why is it just showing this all of the sudden when I try to copy from a zip?

Comment: So did that work? I am not sure exactly why the error occurred but if I can guess, it would be because Windows thinks the files' source and destination address is exactly the same. So overwriting is at risk and some duplicates or errors may occur. Also, note there is almost 40 000 files. Would you really want to pimp your desktop with all those files?

Comment: @RudolphIt did work but the problem is, The zip doesn't have 40 000 files. I have no idea where he gets the 40 000 files.

Comment: Not sure about that one. Consider switching to teracopy. As an opinion from my side, I did not like Windows copy from the beginning and have used teracopy for years.

Comment: This usually happens when you try to copy a directory within itself so... if you try to copy say c:\folder1 and try to copy it into c:\folder1\folder2...

Comment: @TheX Well how is the target directory desktop the same as source desktop??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This message means you're trying to copy files from (ex. Desktop to Desktop) which doesn't do anything. Not sure why this is happening but try copying it to a different folder like Pictures (just temporarily).

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious...does the original ZIP file actually have the ".ZIP" extension? If not, its name may be exactly the same as the Destination file...

Also, about the 40,000 files...it MAY be possible that these are .tmp files from older saves. Long shot, but I've seen it before. It comes from doing "save" instead of "save as" and wiping out older versions.